# ViewDoesNotExist Error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i am trying to do a simple Django application where employee list is read from database and displayed. for that i defined the models and entered the values to database through Django admin. But while trying to display data from database i am stuck with an error, "ViewDoesNotExist at /employeeProfile/ : Could not import task.employeeDetails.views. Error was: cannot import name emp_profile ".I am relatively new to django,so please help me to solve this. i will paste the code here.`enter code here`
VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.models import*
from task.employeeDetails.models import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from task.employeeDetails import emp_profile

def employeeList(request):
    tableList = EmployeeDetails.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('employeeList.html', {'emp_list': tableList})

def employeeProfile(request):
    profile = EmployeeDetails.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('employeeProfile.html',{'emp_profile':emp_profile})
```

URLS.PY

```
(r'^employeeProfile/$','task.employeeDetails.views.employeeProfile'),
```

TEMPLATE

```
<html>
<body>

{%for emp in emp_profile%}
<tr> <td>{{ emp.userName }} {{ emp.designation }} {{  emp.employeeID }}</td> </tr><td>
{%endfor%}
</table></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you run `./manage.py shell`, are you able to import employeeDetails.views? If not, would you mind providing the full backtrace?

Comment: i have given two urls, first one is employeeList and second one is employeeProfile. I am getting values displayed in the first url (employeeList). but getting the above error for 'employeeProfile' url.I followed the same pattern for both the urls, since both are doing the same displaying data from same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def employeeProfile(request):
    profile = EmployeeDetails.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('employeeProfile.html',{'emp_profile':emp_profile})
```

You named it `profile` on line 2, and then you tried to put it in the dictionary as `emp_profile` on line 3.

Comment: This is weird but the error is coming from the last line of the imports  "cannot import name `emp_profile`"

Comment: Django is probably trapping the error. It has nothing to do with the view not existing, and everything to do with a `NameError` getting thrown when he tries to refer to a variable (`emp_profile`) that hasn't actually been declared.

Answer (score 1):

`from task.employeeDetails import emp_profile`

What is `emp_profile` and where **exactly** is it? from the looks of it, `employeeDetails` is the name of your directory, so unless `emp_profile` is a file in `employeeDetails/`, is defined in `employeeDetails/__init__.py` (or otherwise imported there), it will throw an import error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want:

```
def employeeProfile(request): profile = EmployeeDetails.objects.all() 
return render_to_response('employeeProfile.html',{'emp_profile':profile})
```

As Yuji pointed out, it looks like emp_profile isn't defined anywhere

Comment: That was tangent. I'm saying it IS defined via import on line 6. That's why I'm confused changing the view function reference to emp_profile to profile would solve anything.. shouldn't it still raise an import error?

Comment: Oh. Good call, @Yuji. I think his editor probably auto_generated that line, and that probably was what was actually triggering the ImportError. :)

Comment: @tangentstorm --- ohh, I didn't even know that happnens. My editor is so unmagical. :D